# Импорт данных из текстовых файлов в базу данных sqllite

Tags: python, sqlite

Загружаю в столбец бд (Time_requ.db) в таблицу(Time_requ5) данные из текстового файла (1.txt) в столбец time_requ.
Подскажите, как в другой столбец (Request) загружать данные из другого текстового файла(01.txt). Получается загрузить только из одного..заранее спасибо.

```
import sqlite3
import random

#with open('01.txt','r')as log:
    #for line in log:
        #l+=line
        #Request=line.rstrip('\n')


Time=''

with open('1.txt','r')as log1:
    for line1 in log1:
        time_requ=line1.rstrip('\n')
        data.append((Time, Request, time_requ))

conn = sqlite3.connect("Time_requ.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE Time_requ5( Time, Request, time_requ )""")



cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO Time_requ5 VALUES (?,?,?)", data)
conn.commit()
```

Comment: Открывай все три файла, читай по одной записи, и все три в одну запись и вставляй.

Comment: Все три файла можно открыть в одном `with`: `with open(...) as file1, open(...) as file2 ...`.

Comment: Опечатался. Не три. Множество файлов :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наиболее понятный код:

```py
data = []

with open("requests.txt", "r") as fp1, open("time_equs.txt", "r") as fp2:
    for line1, line2 in zip(fp1, fp2):  # Читаем как будто из двух файлов сразу
        Request = line1.rstrip()
        time_requ = line2.rstrip()
        data.append((Time, Request.rstrip(), time_requ.rstrip())
```

---

Наиболее **Pythonic**:

```py
with open("requests.txt", "r") as fp1, open("time_equs.txt", "r") as fp2:
    data = list(map(lambda Request, time_requ: (Time, Request.rstrip(), time_requ.strip()), fp1, fp2))
```

Comment: Михаил, спасибо огромное! Все получилось